# What does it mean that, with -X, you can change the method keyword curl selects, but you will not modify curl's behavior?

Tags: curl

From https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#More_on_changed_methods

> It should be noted that **curl selects which methods to use on its own
>   depending on what action to ask for**. -d will do POST, -I will do HEAD
>   and so on. **If you use the --request / -X option you can change the
>   method keyword curl selects, but you will not modify curl's behavior.**
>   This means that if you for example use -d "data" to do a POST, you can
>   modify the method to a PROPFIND with -X and curl will still think it
>   sends a POST. You can change the normal GET to a POST method by simply
>   adding -X POST in a command line like:
>
> ```
>  curl -X POST http://example.org/
> ```
>
> ... but curl will still think and act as if it sent a GET so it won't
>   send any request body etc.

1. What does "action" mean in " curl selects which methods to use on
   its own depending on what action to ask for"?
2. What does it mean by "If you use the --request / -X option"

   - "you can change the method keyword curl selects",
   - "but you will not modify curl's behavior"?

   Isn't how a server handles a request what matters?   Doesn't that
   only depend on what is written into the request message, and
   therefore on "the method keyword curl selects"?

   What is "curl's behavior"? How does that matter? Does that modify
   the request message (in particular, the HTTP method in the request
   message)?
3. Is that a design bug of curl? What is the purpose for allowing
   inconsistency of specifying HTTP methods?

   If we can specify HTTP method implicitly by action, why do we need to specify HTTP method explicitly by -X?

For example, the command in the quote will retrieve a HTML document, and is that exactly what GET does?

```
$ curl --trace-ascii dump -X POST http://example.org/
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>411 - Length Required</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>411 - Length Required</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

the request sent by the command is below. The HTTP method is POST, which is seen by the server:

```
== Info:   Trying 93.184.216.34...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to example.org (93.184.216.34) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 76 bytes (0x4c)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: Host: example.org
0024: User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
003d: Accept: */*
004a: 
<= Recv header, 30 bytes (0x1e)
0000: HTTP/1.1 411 Length Required
<= Recv header, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: Content-Type: text/html
<= Recv header, 21 bytes (0x15)
0000: Content-Length: 357
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: Connection: close
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Mon, 10 Feb 2020 12:23:42 GMT
<= Recv header, 25 bytes (0x19)
0000: Server: ECSF (nyb/1D33)
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 357 bytes (0x165)
0000: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>.<!DOCTYPE html PUBLI
0040: C "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN".         "http://www.
0080: w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">.<html xmlns="http
00c0: ://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">..<head>...<ti
0100: tle>411 - Length Required</title>..</head>..<body>...<h1>411 - L
0140: ength Required</h1>..</body>.</html>.
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Well, curl's docs are assuming that you already know how http works. Working it out from the curl's docs is backwards. For the "length required" error, see [6.5.10](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.10). If you change curl's method by hand with `-X`, curl will just change the "action" field in the request, not guess what headers are required or forbidden for that action.

Comment: Is what headers are required or forbidden for an action different for different servers, or the same  for all the servers?   What is the purpose for allowing inconsistency of specifying HTTP methods? Is that a design bug of curl?

If we can specify HTTP method implicitly by action, why do we need to specify HTTP method explicitly by -X?

Comment: __1.__ Every server is free to do whatever it likes -- you should always be prepared to handle errors. Most servers DO require a Content-Length with a `POST`. __2.__ Because the HTTP protocol is extensible. A server may accept an `EXTERMINATE` method and act on it. __3.__ No. __4.__ See 2.: In order to use methods curl doesn't know about.

Comment: Thanks. "Every server is free to do whatever it likes -- you should always be prepared to handle errors. Most servers DO require a Content-Length with a POST." Does  the HTTP protocol given HTTP servers the freedom to do so, or have requirements of what headers to be used or what not with each HTTP method but HTTP servers don't comply?

Comment: Have you looked at the link provided by mosvy? All that’s explained there. Note the use of “SHOULD”, “MUST NOT” etc. in the [definition of `Content-Length`](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.2).

Comment: @mosvy "Every server is free to do whatever it likes -- you should always be prepared to handle errors". By "you" do you mean an implementer of a web server? Does a web application/service developer have to handle such errors about required or forbidden headers?

Comment: Look at [WebDAV](http://www.webdav.org/) for one major example of extensions to the set of HTTP methods.

Comment: @StephenKitt  If two servers   can process POST (or GET, PUT, DELETE) requests, do they necessarily have the same sets of required/forbidden headers all the time? Do they also always have the same nonempty set of optional headers? I guess both yes, and that is specified by HTTP?

Comment: If HTTP specifies that a given header is required or forbidden, then all compliant servers must respect that. The set of optional headers is defined by HTTP, not by implementations, but since they’re optional, implementations can handle them differently (as specified by HTTP).

Comment: By you, I mean of course whoever makes a request to the server. Since curl passes the errors up to its caller, it means you, the curl's operator. And yes, it's perfectly legit for a server to accept a POST request without Content-Length, there's nothing in the standard which prevents it, the standard just specifies that a request without Content-Length or Transfer-Encoding should be assumed to [__not__ have a message body](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.3.3). And it's not even up to the server -- the server may relay the requests to php scripts and such.

Answer (score 1):

> What does "action" mean in " curl selects which methods to use on its own depending on what action to ask for"?

See [the section on the HTTP protocol](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#The_HTTP_Protocol), which “defines” the term:

> HTTP is plain ASCII text lines being sent by the client to a server to request a particular action, and then the server replies a few text lines before the actual requested content is sent to the client.

The action is whatever is being asked of the HTTP server: retrieve data (which corresponds to the `GET` method), add a resource (the `PUT` method), send data to an existing resource (the `POST` method) etc.

> Isn't how a server handles a request what matters? Doesn't that only depend on what is written into the request message, and therefore on "the method keyword curl selects"?

Yes, but the overall message which is sent has to match the expectations set by the chosen method. Your example illustrates this: `curl` constructs a valid message for the `GET` method, but you override that to specify a `POST` method, and the constructed message isn’t valid for `POST`, which causes the server to respond with an error.

The `-X` option overrides the method without changing any of the surrounding behaviour.

Comment: Thanks. Is that a design bug of curl? What is the purpose for allowing
    inconsistency between two ways of specifying HTTP methods?

Comment: If we can specify HTTP method implicitly by action, why do we need to specify HTTP method explicitly by -X?

Comment: It’s not a design bug, it’s really a debugging option IMO. As mentioned in the docs, “Normally you  don't need this option. All sorts of GET, HEAD, POST and PUT requests are rather invoked by using dedicated command line options.”

Answer (score 1):

> What does "action" mean in " curl selects which methods to use on its own depending on what action to ask for"?

I think it refers to the various options that modify what curl does. It doesn't look like they'd be explicitly called "actions" in the man page, but if they say "Requests X using method FOO", then it would seem to apply. `-I`/`--head` asks for headers only, so it uses `HEAD`, `--data` uses `POST`, and `--data --get` uses `GET`. Note that the quoted text explicitly refers to `-I` and `-d`, right after the bolded part.

That last pair is important, with `GET` the data is sent along with the URL, i.e. `...?data_here`, with `POST`, it's sent as the contents of the HTTP request

With `curl --data foo=bar http://host/path/to/foo.pl` we get

```
POST /path/to/foo.pl HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar
```

and with `curl --data foo=bar --get http://host/path/to/foo.pl`

```
GET /path/to/foo.pl?foo=bar HTTP/1.1
```

> What does it mean by "If you use the --request / -X option" you can change the method keyword curl selects, but you will not modify curl's behavior.

Using `-X GET` doesn't change where the data goes (or how it's encoded). With `--data foo=bar -X GET`, `curl` still thinks it's doing a `POST`, so it posts the data in the request body, just renaming the method (below). This will probably not work here, but would with `-X XYZ`, if `XYZ` was a method that expected the data in the request body like `POST`.

```
GET /path/to/foo.pl HTTP/1.1
Content-Length: 7
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

foo=bar
```